# Swift 3 test if SKSpriteNode subclass of SKNode contains touches

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

```
class MainNode:SKNode {
    class Box: SKSpriteNode {
        override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
            super.init(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "testIMG1"), color: UIColor.clear, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        }
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
    var subclassNode: SKSpriteNode!
    var box = Box()

    convenience init(size: CGSize) {
        self.init()

        box = Box()
        box.position.x = 0

        subclassNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
        subclassNode.position.x =  0
        subclassNode.zPosition = 6

        self.addChild(subclassNode)
    }
}
```

In my class `MainNode` im trying to test if the SKSpriteNode subclass `Box` contains the touches in my GameScene

adding

```
for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    if MainNode.SubclassNode.contains(location) {
        print("Subclass contains touch")
    }
}
```

to either my GameScene class or my `MainNode` class does not seem to work at all even when `SubclassNode.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

how can I determine the if the touch is in my subclass?

Comment: you are using the wrong method,  you want to use `atPoint` to get a node at a point and check if that node is SubclassNode.  Also I would recommend not starting your variables with a capital letter, it is going to cause confusion.  Types should be capital, while variables should be lower.

Comment: could you give me an example? also i gave the subclass a name and it still does not work. (sorry about the capital letter i normally do lower-case. this is some edited code and i wasnt really paying attention)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with some more research and help from [KnightOfDragon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2709645/knight0fdragon)

I set `self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` and then gave my subclassNode a name `subclassNode.name = "SubclassNode"` then I added this code into my `MainNode` class

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchedNode = self.atPoint(location)
        if let name = touchedNode.name
        {
            if name == "SubclassNode" {
                print("touched Subclass Node")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is why I try not to answer sometimes,  a little research goes a long way.  The more you teach yourself, the better off you will be when attempting to solve problems.

Comment: thanks for that advice!  Ii will do more research before jumping to conclusions next time.